# Pointers on how to create a coded user interface in iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

What are the guidelines I should follow to create a full fledged user interface without an interface build ?

I just about finished educating myself in creating Android Applications. I stuck to the method of creating the user interface via **XML files** and not the Visual UI Builder.

Now I would like to understand how to build user interfaces via code. I would not want to use **Storyboards** or **XIB files**.

From reading around tutorials and other material. I figured the following

- There is a no way one can construct the user interfaces like how android does it, with their **layout .xml files**
- XIB and Storyboards are the preferred method to create user interfaces. Storyboards might be the primary tool in the future.

To insert a widget programmatically

```
- Create a frame using CGRectMake
- Create the elements / Widget and mention its frame
- Insert a widget via view.addSubView: widget
```

Is this the only way I can create user interfaces without the builder ? What are the guidelines I should follow while creating views ?

Comment: google - create uiviewcontroller programmatically

Comment: I strongly suggest learning how to work with Auto Layout programmatically. This is a very common and my favourite way of doing layout (a lot of companies avoid storyboards and nibs for the most part)

Answer (score 2):

XIB and Storyboards [created with InterfaceBuilder in Xcode] are the GUI Way of creating a view in iOS. In my opinion you should explore those. you can do more with less code. You can go for programmatically adding/removing views when you create complex UIs.

However, if you still want to code the views programmatically there are so many resources out there.. i quickly managed to get the below
http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/

It is not recommended to use hard frames with CGRect for your views anymore.. Autolayout is the way to go..

Comment: Ah, thanks. Shall read up on AutoLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the information you've read isn't the latest; creating views isn't as compact syntactically as on Android but use of Apple's constraint system is much preferred to messing about calculating your own frames.

The main thing you'll want to add to your knowledge is [`NSLayoutConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/). Its visual format looks a bit goofy at first, and you have to do a bit of manual work for reflectivity but — making the leap that you're probably working with Swift, not Objective-C, as the thing closer to Java — you might say:

```
let blueButton = UIButton()
button.setTitle(...whatever...)
button.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.view.addSubview(blueButton)

let redButton = UIButton()
// etc, as above

// a dictionary of views to representative names; this is what
// I mean by you doing the work for reflectivity, i.e. associating
// names with things
let views = [ "red" : redButton, "blue" : blueButton]
self.view.addConstraints(
   NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[red]-[blue]-|" 
                        options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(0) metrics:nil views:views))
```

The `|`s reference the outside of `self.view`s main area of content, the `-`s represent normal spacers and `[red]` and `[blue]` mean "the views I called 'red' and 'blue' within the `views` dictionary". After adding constraints, UIKit will ensure they are met automatically, including during view resizes. Try a quick demo app with portrait and landscape orientations and give your device a rotation to see that in practice.

There are a bunch of other things you can put into the visual constraint format — vertical constraints, fixed, minimum and maximum sizes, etc — and a bunch more you can create programmatically, e.g. view must be at least 33% as large as this other view.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Your answer was very informative. Giving constraints a shot right now!